# How to get .app file of a xcode application

Tags: xcode, .app, deriveddata

I have created an xcode project. Now I want to give .app file to my friend to use that application. From where do I get this file? How to install this .app file in his Applications folder using an installer package?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Build a release version, and the .app file is under build/Release folder of your project. Just copy it to Applications folder of your friend's machine. I don't think you need to build a installer.

Comment: i need to install some supporting components with that .app file. Thats why i have created installer package. but that install every thing except .app file. How to install that .app file? I got that accetpted mark.

Comment: @Nelson this begs the question... what is the correct answer in Xcode 4?

Comment: @Greg, in the navigator (left pane), expand the group "Products" and right-click on the .app file and choose "show in finder". There it is!

Comment: Sufian's comment is correct. It worked for me. If you want the Release version, you must build the app accordingly with the correct build scheme. To create a new build scheme, go to Product -> Scheme -> New Scheme. Open the new scheme, and in the Archive tab, Choose the Release configuration. Do the same in the Run tab. Then build your app. This will create the .app file in the "release-iphoneos" folder. You can also find the .app file by right-clicking it in the Products directory in the source pane on the left and selecting "Show in Finder".

Answer (score 89):

You can find the .app file here:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{app name}/Build/Products/Deployment/
```

Credit for the path location goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9673810/1208218)

SIDENOTE: I had a lot of fun trying to get this into my iPad after that. It worked however. Using Snow Leopard + Xcode 4.2 + iPad with IOS 5.1.1 :) - I used the iPhone configuration utility to get the app into the ipad (you have to add the app, then click on the device, then click "install" behind the app you just added in the "application library" of iphone configuration utility) and had to create a [Distribution Provisioning Profile](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/provisioningprofiles/viewDistributionProfiles.action) and get the [WWDR certificate](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/distribute.action) and finally change the build settings in Xcode after all the certificates were in place. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html)

But after much fun I am now looking at my first app on my iPad :) - btw, for getting apps into the app store you need to create a app store Distribution Provisioning Profile, while for ad hoc installs like these you create an ad hoc one. There is a bit more to it, but I think these are the most important and tricky steps. Enjoy.

PS. Just remembered that you also have to set the build type (top left of Xcode) to "iOS device", otherwise it will never sign your application. So the path name above only has limited value: yes, it will have the .app file in it, but no you can't upload it (at least not using the iPhone configuration utility) since it is not code signed - you will get an "Could not copy validate signature" error. So change it to "iOS device" and build (remember to select the right certificates in the build section of Xcode as per the url info above). In that same build section, you can also set the "Installation Build Products Location" to a different path, so that you can determine where the .app (the one that is properly code signed) ends up.

**Xcode 12.5**

Can be found in the following directory ->

```sh
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{app name}/Build/Products/{scheme}-iphonesimulator/{app name}.app
```

Answer (score 55):

1. xCode window tab
2. Organizer
3. Right click to the archive you want to get app
4. Show in finder
5. Right click to (ProductName….). xcarchive file
6. Show package contents
7. Products
8. Applications

**Finally** - THERE IS YOUR .APP PROJECT FILE !

Comment: This is a good solution when you want to know exactly what version of the app you are getting. I found the other methods that use the DerivedData confusing in that regard.

Comment: As my answer's 3. part, you can select which version you want to  get app file.

Answer (score 34):

The application will appear in your projects Build directory. In the source pane on the left of the Xcode window you should see a section called 'Products'. Listed under there will be your application name. If you right-click on this you can select 'Reveal in Finder' to be taken to the application in the Finder. You can send this to your friend directly and he can just copy it into his Applications folder. Most applications do not require an installer package on Mac OS X.

Comment: This applies to iOS as well, but note that there are multiple versions of the .app file, and by default this took me to "Release-iphoneos" instead of "Release-iphonesimulator". You want to use the latter if you're going to install it on a simulator using xcrun simctl install

Answer (score 13):

Under Xcode 4.5.2, you can find the .app file in this way:

1. Select Window > Organizer in the Xcode's menu(or just press 'Shift+Command+2')
2. Select your project on the left side of Organizer, and you will find the Derived Data path on the right side. Just click the mini arrow in the end of the path, this will open Finder at the path.
3. In the Finder, click "Build > Products > Release", you will find the .app.

Answer (score 10):

I know as for Appium Mobile Automation you need .app file to run ios app on Simulator.So as like me many of you face this problem.
So I explain how to create that .app file and where it is located.

1.Open Xcode.

2.Click on your sample project.(If you don't have then click on create new xcode project)

3.In left panel inside screen you will see products folder then click and expand that, you will see the list.

4. Then right click on .app file and click on Show in Finder and thats your .app file. Now you can copy or use that path in capabilities for appium desktop or in framework.

[image: Check the attached screenshot for detail]

Answer (score 9):

Xcode 8.1

Product -> Archive
Then export on the right hand side to somewhere on your drive.

Comment: When I use this option at XCode 9+, it gives an .ipa file. Is it possible to get .app   file using *XCode Organizer* ? If yes, how?

Comment: I found. Right click on archive and select _Show In Finder_. Then right click on _.xcarchive_ file and choose _Show Package Contents_. *.app* file is in _Product > Applications_ folder.

Answer (score 6):

In Xcode 7 a quick way is to use Product > Archive. It's probably not a signed copy for submission but it's good enough to give to somebody else for testing.

Answer (score 1):

In the navigator (left pane), expand the group "Products" and right-click on the .app file and choose "Show in Finder". There it is! :)