# Xcode 4 - How do I get the .app file?

Tags: xcode4

I installed Xcode 4, it has very cool features. 
I developed my new app with Xcode 4 and its time give it to client for their testing.

The problem is the that I am not able to get the .app file in finder. Under product category when I choose the .app file and right click on it there is no option for "show in finder".

I need that file so I can send it to client for testing. In the Xcode 3, the option was there.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could also select Product -> Build For -> Archiving, then expand the Products folder in the navigator, right-click the app and choose Show in Finder.

Answer (score 11):

~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{app name}/Build/Products/Deployment/

Comment: Thank you! The .app is indeed there! (background: With my xcode 4.2 and iOS 5.1.1 ipad, this is the only place I can get/find the .app file and then use it to drag it to iTunes and get it to work, without upgrading to Lion (ftm - waiting for Mountain Lion to be released))

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the Product->Archive function instead. You can then access the archive from Organiser. Share the archive and then save it to disk - this creates a .ipa file which can then be distributed for testing.

As ever though, [comprehensive documentation on this matter from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/DistApps/DistApps.html) will guide the way.