# Xcode 4.2 (Snow Leopard) and iOS 5.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ios 5.1 with xcode 4.2 for iOS development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565/ios-5-1-with-xcode-4-2-for-ios-development)

I updated my iPhone to iOS 5.1. 
My operating system is Snow Leopard.
Now I need the sdk 5.1 to develop, with xcode 4.2.

Where can I download it?
Any suggest?

**Solution:**
Downgrade to ios5.0 or update to Lion

Comment: Same question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565/ios-5-1-with-xcode-4-2-for-ios-development/9613774#comment12199185_9613774

Comment: Please don't edit answers, to thank for a solution, but vote them up, and mark one of them as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't.

You need to update to Mac OS 10.7 Lion in order to get the latest version of Xcode with the 5.1 SDK.

The last installable version of Xcode on Snow Leopard will be 4.2. Apple *really* wants developers to keep up to date on everything, whether MacOS or iOS.

Comment: The solution is to downgrade my iPhone to iOS 5.0?

Comment: You can't downgrade your iThing. Once you you have gone up you can't go down. Update to Lion

Comment: @MichaelDautermann do you have a reference quoting that 4.2 w/ iOS 5 is the final 10.6 version? Just curious.

Comment: Unfortunately, my machine doesn't support Lion. I really wish Apple had made this clear. I don't understand why they've done this except to force people to upgrade.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but it's also a pretty crappy one.  Though that's entirely Apple's fault.

Comment: Sometimes I hate Apple.  Like now.

Comment: Apple did a poor job of communicating that 5.1 was Lion-only. I would have waited to upgrade my devices when a OS upgrade was more convenient.

Answer (score 55):

To get Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard to run code on a device running 5.1 you can do this:

If you have another Mac running Lion + XCode 4.3.1 you can copy the files from:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.1 (9B176)
```

to the equivalent place on your SL Mac: probably

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
```

and also copy `version.plist` from the Lion machine in the `iPhoneOS.platform` folder to the SL machine.

Re-start XCode on the SL machine and re-connect the devices and it seems happy enough.

[Edit: If you don't have access to a machine with Lion+4.3.1 you can get the files out of the 4.3.1 DMG which can be downloaded from Apple here: http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.3.1_for_lion/xcode_4.3.1_for_lion.dmg

then mount the DMG, Show Package Contents on the XCode icon and drill down to

```
/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport to
```

find the files mentioned above.]

In steps:

1. Stop XCode on SL machine
2. Disconnect your iphone
3. Mount the Xcode 4.3.1 image (.dmg that you can download from Apple dev site)
4. Show package contentes of the Xcode 4.3.1
5. copy `XCode/Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.1 (9B176)` 
   to `<HD>/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`
6. copy `XCode/Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/version.plist` 
   to `<HD>/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/`
7. Start Xcode
8. connect your iphone and it should work.

Comment: There are a few other folders to grab. See https://devforums.apple.com/message/630144#630144

Comment: sadly the 4.3.1 dmg has since disappeared and standalone dmg install is being deprecated in favor of app store install of xcode, not clear you will be able to get the dmg from that in the future. with careful hunting & cursing it's possible to find the 4.3.2 dmg (http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.3.2/xcode_432_lion.dmg), but this may be the last dmg available and i don't yet know if the workaround above works with this dmg, waiting for it to d/l.

Comment: hooray, same instructions work for the 4.3.2 dmg. be sure to also follow the advice to copy the `/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Develope‌​r/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk` files from the DMG into your `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/`, otherwise debug is fairly broken. You will also want to do a clean build or your breakpoints won't work.

Comment: it still doesn't seem to work for me. I re-installed xcode 4.2 from clean and copied those files to the folder. But xcode still doesn't recognize device... and Organizer claims bout permission to save file such that "You don’t have permission to save the file “iOS DeviceSupport” in the folder “Xcode”." Any idea?? I can't do anything... ugh

Comment: I guess... device version does not match. In 4.3.1 xcode supports 5.1(9B176) but my device (4s) is under 5.1(9B179)....

Comment: It worked! I copied over a lot of other files as well, including the simulator SDKs, and making the latest alias point to 5.1. :)

Comment: No surprise here really, but [XCode 4.3.3](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.3.3_for_lion/xcode_4.3.3_for_lion.dmg) is available at [http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.3.3_for_lion/xcode_4.3.3_for_lion.dmg](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.3.3_for_lion/xcode_4.3.3_for_lion.dmg).

Comment: Works like a charm. Spent almost 2 days to get this sorted .Finally this solution helped.

Comment: Works like a charm, also for the 4.4.1 update.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay on Snow Leopard, download the iOS 5.0.1 firmware of your device on this link : http://www.iphonefirmware.com/firmwares-download.

And do a manual restore on iTunes.

I did it today (March 8, 2012) on my iPad 2 and it works, Apple still seems to sign this iOS version.I guess not for a long time,  so do it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 5.1 is only avalaible in xCode 4.3.1, and its only avalaible in Lion, sorry.

YOu can try changing the version of your mac and faking it to install 4.3.1, but I cannot assure you its going to work...