# Why am I getting this "libxml/tree.h file not found" error?

Tags: iphone, xcode, libxml2

I just installed Xcode version 4.3.1 and I get this error:

> libxml / tree.h file not found

I have also installed Xcode 4.2, and with the same project I get the same error.

I have configured the *header search paths* with `/usr/include/libxml2`
I also tried `$(SDKROOT) / usr/include/libxml2` and it didn't work.

I have also put *Other Linker Flag* with `lxml2`

Answer (score 100):

Include the following in your header search path and you should be immune to any weirdness Apple does with their Xcode updates:

```
$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I also had to set to YES to "Always Search User Paths"

Comment: This worked for me **with** setting `Always Search User Paths` to `NO`

Comment: Just in case anyone is in the same situation I was: remember to add the search path also to the test target.

Answer (score 27):

In your question, you have a space between the `/` and `usr`.  Perhaps this is a typo, but the path is:

```
/usr/include/libxml2
```

Just confirm that is the path in the target build settings:

[image: Target build settings]

You can also verify that the path exists on your file system.

Comment: This free space must have been a mistake to copy and paste ...

I have marked the option to Always Search User Path to YES, and does not work: (

Comment: Are you importing the header like: `#import <libxml/tree.h>`?  Also check the answer to [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428847/libxml-tree-h-no-such-file-or-directory) on SO.

Comment: So far I've solved it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614918/xcode-4-2-snow-leopard-and-ios-5-1

Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

LibXML2 library solved

SOLUTION!

if you have xcode 4.3.x in /Application

need ONLY add: "/usr/include/libxml2" without quote in Application TARGET -> Header search path.

for this -> double click on the line -> on little window click plus sign an write /usr/include/libxml2

nb - need also add libxml2.dylib to the framework. I  use 2.2.7.3

hope help you

Answer (score 8):

I solved the problem by setting the Header Search Path to:

```
${SDK_DIR}/usr/include/libxml2
```

and Always Search User Paths to NO (which is strongly suggested anyway)
This just in the target.

Answer (score 7):

It appears in 4.3.1, you need to include the Header Search Paths in the Targets as well as the project.  I'm not sure if this was an issue with moving from 4.2 to 4.3.1, but I just update to Lion and ran into the same issue.

Comment: Adding to the target is enought. What is the point of adding it to the project then anyway?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this again today, I would recommend you wrap the path in quotes:

```
"$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2"
```

I wasted half an hour on this due to having spaces in my path.

Answer (score 3):

The correct path is (for 'Header Search Path'):

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/**

Comment: It's definitely an issue when updating to Xcode 4.3.1, as an app I had working just fine started failing. Adding this to the header search path IN ADDITION TO /usr/include/libxml2 (and checking recursive for both) seems to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem.

I try set path( 'Header Search Path') to `/usr/include/libxml2` ,build error!

I try set path( 'Header Search Path') to `$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2` ,build error!

but I set path to

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/usr/include/libxml2
```

build succeeded!

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 6:

Do the following:

1.0)Select "mainApp" Target : Go to settings ->In "Header Search Path"

1.1)Add this:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/libxml2.

2.0)Select "TestApp" Target : Go to settings ->In "Header Search Path"

2.1)Add this:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/libxml2.

Answer (score 2):

2 solutions:

1. header search path should be updated with SDK root as such: `$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2`
2. Install command line tools for XCode 5 from terminal by entering: `xcode-select --install`
   XCode 4 should have the command line tools install option in preferences>downloads section.

I'd personally go with the second one.

Answer (score 0):

I had to configure the `other Linker Flags` like this: 
for Debug and Release do `Add Build Settings` (lower right corner) and `Add Conditional Settings`. Then, select `Any iOS Simulator SDK` and insert the Setting `-lxml2`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the main difficulty was that the app is composed of two projects, with the second one having several targets. It took me a while to realise that the error was occurring in one of those targets and not in the target of the main project. Then I just had to add the (in)famous `$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2` in the Header Search Paths of that particular target.

I am using Xcode Version 5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I already had the header search path and frame work but was getting this error. Forcefully quitting xcode and then restarting it worked for me (I was using xcode 7.2)

Comment: Although, question is old enough but may be the answer can help someone

Answer (score 0):

In debug/release add the search path to Any Architecture | Any SDK
That is click the + button near debug and add ${SDKROOT}/usr/include/libxml2
Similarly do the above for release also