# How to use libxml in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I try to use this new language to start a new project with Some of my old code,
I used Libxml2.2 in my old project,so xcode shows "libxml.h/parse.h file not found" after my putting the code in my new project.
i have already imported the "libxml2.2.dylib"

Comment: This is good read https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/02/23/c-libraries-swift/

Answer (score 9):

I 've made it work with CommonCrypto https://github.com/onmyway133/CommonCrypto.swift but libxml should be the same. Things to keep in mind

**module.modulemap**

Read http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#module-map-language

Create a folder named `libxml2` (in my case, it is at the same directory as my project file), then create a `module.modulemap` file inside

```
module libxml2 {
  header "/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h"
  export *
}
```

Here I add just `tree.h`, but you can add more for your need

**SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS**

Go to Target Build Settings, add this into `Import Paths`

```
${SRCROOT}/libxml2
```

**HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS**

Read [Why am I getting this "libxml/tree.h file not found" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666804/why-am-i-getting-this-libxml-tree-h-file-not-found-error)

Go to Target Build Settings, add this into `Header Search Paths`

```
$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2
```

**Interesting related posts**

- [Swift Framework with libxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171680/swift-framework-with-libxml)
- https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/02/23/c-libraries-swift/
- [Importing CommonCrypto in a Swift framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248598/importing-commoncrypto-in-a-swift-framework)
- https://github.com/onmyway133/Reindeer

Answer (score 6):

To get this working with my project in Xcode 6, I navigated to "Build Settings" for my project, and selected my target. I then searched for "Header Search Paths" in the Build Settings, and added the following line to both debug and release:

```
$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2
```

Comment: This is not working, as the compiler will says that you can't include non-modular include

Comment: There is  currently a modulemap file for libxml2; perhaps it didn't exist when this question/comment were written. Note that that file actually suggests that you "Add "-Xcc -I$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2" to OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS in Xcode project" as of Xcode 9.

Answer (score 2):

I found that you can leave out importing 'libxml2.2.dylib' if you add '-lxml2' to OTHER_LDFLAGS.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create a custom `module map` file containing the header of `libxml/tree.h` like so :

```
module libxml [system] {
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h"
    export *
}
```

Then you place this file (module.modulemap) inside a folder -module for example- and add it to your project's and target's `build settings`.

You can now use `@import libxml;` in your code.