# Could not build Objective-C module 'libxml'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode9.3

We have integrated libxml in a swift project following the instructions mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301381/how-to-use-libxml-in-swift) by creating `module.modulemap` file.

Code in module.modulemap file is

```
module libxml [system] {
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h"
    export *
}
```

Now with Xcode 9.3 we are getting following errors:

> import libxml --- Could not build Objective-C module 'libxml'

```
struct _xmlEnumeration {
    struct _xmlEnumeration    *next;    /* next one */
    const xmlChar            *name; /* Enumeration name */
};
```

Error :

> Type 'struct _xmlEnumeration' has incompatible definitions in different translation units

Has anyone face this issue after migrating to Xcode 9.3. Please help.

Comment: What path do you have in your project settings ? under `Search Paths > Header Search` ?

Comment: I have given $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2