# libxml/tree.h file not found in xcode 7.0

Tags: ios, wsdl, xcode7, libxml2, ios-frameworks

I have use the `WSDL2ObjC` framework for WSDL Service but it will give me error in `WSDL2ObjC` Class:

> libxml/tree.h file not found.

I Tried:

- Add the framework `libxml2.dylib`.
- Header Search Paths `$SDKROOT/usr/include/libxml2` or
  `/usr/include/libxml2` use both one by one
- Add "-lxml2" to the Other Linker Flags property
- Add "-I/usr/include/libxml2" to the Other C Flags property
- Add the `CFNetwork.framework`

Set all these Settings, but it did not worked.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting this "libxml/tree.h file not found" error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666804/why-am-i-getting-this-libxml-tree-h-file-not-found-error)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Editor : Build Settings : Search Paths : Header Search Paths

Add this to header search path:

$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2

I think it was the lack of the parentheses around SDKROOT.

Comment: worked for me on macOS and Hpple, will try soon on iOS