# Xcode builds for some 9B206 devices but not for others

Tags: xcode, ios5, compilation, unity-game-engine

I'm using version 4.2 of Xcode on a Snow Leopard OSX, and I'm having the following problem:

I can compile the code and run just fine on three different iPads that have the iOS5.1.1(9B206) installed on them. However, when I try it on another iPad or another iPhone that have the same iOS installed, it will give me the following error:

"The version of iOS on “iPad” does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.

OS Installed on iPad
5.1.1 (9B206)

Xcode Supported iOS Versions
Latest
5.0 (9A334)
4.3
4.2"

Even though it has already successfully built for other 9B206 devices. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Possibly helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614918/xcode-4-2-snow-leopard-and-ios-5-1