# iPhone with iOS 5.1 not detected with XCode 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

My XCode 4.2 does not detect iPhone with iOS 5.1.
I have MAC OS X 10.6.7 installed, with XCode 4.2 and iPhone with 5.1

If I build app for iOS 5.0 it works, but not 5.1.

I want to submit my app to appstore today, will it be accepted?

And How do I run app on 5.1 devices?

Please help

Following are my device config:

Developer Information:

Version:  4.2 (4C199)
  Location: /Developer
  Applications:
  Xcode:    4.2 (828)
  Instruments:  4.2 (4233)
  Dashcode: 3.0.2 (336)
  SDKs:
  Mac OS X:
  10.6: (10K549)
  iPhone OS:
  5.0:  (9A334)
  iPhone Simulator:
  3.2:  (7W367a)
  4.0:  (8A400)
  4.1:  (8B117)
  4.2:  (8C134)
  4.3:  (8F192)
  5.0:  (9A334)

Comment: it seems to required a lion with xcode 4.3.1 for ios 5.1 app developing. Apple doesn't supply an update version of xcode 4.2 for snow leopard after ios 5.1's release.

Comment: **Upgrade your Mac to Mac OS Lion (i.e 10.7)**

Comment: This will definitely help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/9621226/1378447

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the developer center Xcode 4.3.1 supports iOS 5.1. The last release of Xcode for OS 10.6 is Xcode 4.2 which supports iOS 5 (this is the release you have).

**You need to upgrade to Mac OS 10.7 and Xcode 4.3 to get support for iOS 5.1**. You can continue to use the 5.0 SDK and build against that as long as you don’t need features in iOS 5.1.

I assume that your phone will continue to not be recognized by Xcode until you upgrade your SDK/Xcode to 5.1.

Answer (score 3):

You have to install latest iOS version (5.1) to your xcode to detect your ios5.1 devices. But it does not included in xcode4.2 installer, so you have to upgrade your OS to 10.7.

There is a way to install iOS sdk 5.1 to your xcode 4.2 running on Mac OS X 10.6.x.

First, you have to download latest xcode installer [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) (mine is xcode_4.3.1_for_lion.dmg, you may have to login to download)

Open terminal (Application->Utilities->Termial) and type these commands:

```
sudo cp -R /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/
sudo cp -R /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/
sudo cp -R /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.1\ \(9B176\) /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/
sudo rm -f /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/Latest
cd /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/
sudo ln -s ./5.1\ \(9B176\) ./Latest
```

Restart you xcode and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

There is a hack the I confirmed working. For further reading check [IOS 5.1 on XCode 4.2 Snow Leopard](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/100229-snow-leopard-sdk-5-1-a.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you upgraded your iPhone/iPad to 5.1 but do not want to upgrade your XCode and Mac OS. Here is a work around for you to be able to still install your app to your testing device:

Sign up to testflightapp.com, upload your app to testflightapp.com and then download it to your device over the air.

By this, you can postpone upgrading to Mac OS 10.7 and Xcode 4.3 for a while. You will not be able to debug/put break points on your app while testing on the device though.

Answer (score 0):

This thing worked for me
**First I ran the project in xcode 3.2.5** and **the project ran on iOS 5.1!!!!**
****Later i disconnected the device and again ran the project on xcode 4.2**** on snow leopard and it started working with out nay problem.Dont know how this worked
I was having snow leopard and old xcode 3.2.5

Answer (score 0):

The above suggestion by prajul does work. Just connect the 5.1 device and authenticate xcode 3.2.5 to collect the details. Then once it starts collecting your xcode4.2 will be able to run the device that has os version 5.1. I got it worked in ipad with ios 5.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

These steps might only be helpful to people with access to `XCode4.2` and `XCode 4.3` both.
Was easy for us, as we have `iMac with XCode 4.3` and a MBP with `SnowLeopard - XCode 4.2`

1. `XCode 4.3`, Sync provisioning profiles from Organizer-`Add Device to Provisioning Portal`
2. `XCode 4.3`, run the application on the device
3. Unplug the device with `iOS 5.1` and connect to `XCode 4.2`