# how to restore back my device to ios 5.0.1?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working on mac mini 32bit. And I also use OS X 10.6.8 and XCode 4.2. I can't build the project on my device upgraded to iOS 5.1. Please help me to make my device to restore back to iOS 5.0.1.

Comment: Afaik there's no way to revert the upgrade. Some people have had success with http://stackoverflow.com/a/9621226/477878 though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no official way to downgrade iOS devices.

Try to look up for "unofficial" methods (involving jailbraking) to downgrade your device to a previous iOS version: http://www.google.com/search?q=downgrade+ios+5.1+to+5.0.1

For the future: you need to be a very careful with Mac OS X and iOS upgrades, if you use older Mac and/or iOS devices. Apple maintains very small backward compatibility for their software, thus, it quite easy to get in situation, when you can't continue your work without hardware upgrade. :(

Answer (score 0):

Apple are no longer signing 5.0.1 - this means that you can't downgrade.

Your easiest solution is to install Lion.

Answer (score 0):

You should start your device in Device Firmware Update (DFU) mode. [Read this](http://osxdaily.com/2010/06/24/iphone-dfu-mode-explained-and-how-to-enter-dfu-mode-on-your-iphone/) on how to do it, the short description of the steps are:

1. Connect your iPhone to iTunes
2. Switch it off
3. Hold the home and the power button together for 10 sec until iTunes detects your iPhone in recovery mode
4. The device' screen remains black
5. To exit from DFU, hold the two buttons together once again.

Once it is connected to iTunes in DFU mode, hold SHIFT while clicking on the restore button and it will open a small window where you can select the firmware version. At least while 5.1 was in beta, it worked so.

I don't know whether in the hundreds of pages of license agreement of iPhone this is mentioned as illegal or not, but you don't need to download anything warez to do this.