# xcode 4.2 to iOS5 device fails ipad2 ipad cannot run using selected device

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios5, ipod

My app was building fine with no issues on my ipad 2 and my ipod touch.  I updated my devices and they are running iOS 5.1 on both devices and now I can't build out to them or run on them.  I get the following warning:

> Xcode cannot run using the selected device.
>   No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version.  Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

what am I doing wrong? Also, I don't see the name of my device like anthony's ipad/ipod
it just says the project name and iOS Device next to it.  It runs great in the simulators. Oh help me please. thank you.  I did look this topic up but I didn't understand the answers I found. or they didn't pertain to iOS 5 help.

Answer (score 3):

Generally with each iOS update Apple updates XCode as well. An older version of XCode will not recognize a new version of iOS. You can update XCode from the App Store or at http://developer.apple.com

Comment: The new Xcode version can be downloaded directly from the Mac App Store.

Comment: @Nate THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I am so grateful to this site and it's users!!!! THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!!  I am a green horned rookie at this site and everyone and everything oozes awesomeness!!! I wish there was a way to give back!!!  I am running both Snow Leopard and Lion (external drive) I will hop onto lion and give it a go.  NATE!!! YOU ARE THE MAN!! THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 2):

You should upgrade to Xcode 4.3.1 which contains the iOS 5.1 SDK.

If you don't want to upgrade (or can't because you have Snow Leopard), you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9621226/1207152) answer that explains how to use Xcode 4.2 with iOS 5.1 devices.

But I still recommend upgrading to Xcode 4.3.1 (and Lion if needed).

Comment: THANK YOU!!! AWESOME!!! This site is awesome because not only do I get an answer...I get THE answer!!! and multiple ones in this case!!! OH PASTA FOR DINNER!!!! YEAH!!! THANK YOU EVERYONE!!!!