# Xcode 4.2 with iOS 5.1 on Snow Leopard - breakpoints not working

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2

I followed the instructions in this post [Is it possible to get the iOS 5.1 SDK for Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565/ios-5-1-with-xcode-4-2-for-ios-development) to get my iOS 5.1 device working with Xcode 4.2. All is working except my breakpoints are not being hit when debugging. Anyone come across this and know a fix.

Regards

Comment: I think this proposition is ought to have some features that may not work as proper SDK installation would. I think you still may not get it working completely as officially there is no SDK in snow leopard with iOS 5.1

Answer (score 1):

maybe not the answer you are looking for but i had problems with ios 5.1 too and i just downloaded the new xcode (4.3.1 i think) and everything works fine, no problem with old project.

Comment: The most recent one is 4.3.2 (since the 20th of March)

Comment: But you need Lion for 4.3.1 or 4.3.2 don't you. I am talking about using iOS5.1 with Snow Leopard

Answer (score 0):

Are breakpoints enabled?  Check the button in the toolbar, or Product -> Debug -> Activate Breakpoints.  We all overlook simple things sometimes so I'm just checking!

Comment: yes breakpoints are enabled, i think its something to do with the 'hack' one needs to do to get this to run as mentioned in the link. Maybe something else is missing

Answer (score 0):

I've used the same installation method you mention to get 5.1 and 6.0.1 SDKs onto Snow Leopard. (Note that just installing the SDKs doesn't include the simulator, so it won't support 5.1+.)

I have Snow Leopard 10.6.8, and breakpoints fire fine, both on my updated phone connected via cable and in the outdated simulator. Should work fine on 10.6.7 also.

I would recommend that you create a new project and set a breakpoint. If that works, you are expecting the other project to reach a breakpoint but it doesn't, either because of the code or an XCode setting.