# iPad and iPhone not allowing testing

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

So I do realize that there are plenty of similar questions based on what I'm asking and yes I have looked through them and tried all their fixes and nothing is working.

My current Xcode version is 4.2

I haven't updated or changed anything with XCode or my devices and they were working last time I used Xcode. Now when I try ANY Xcode project it will not run it on the devices. When I try to run it the only option it gives me is iOS Device (it doesn't display their names there as it normally does). When I run it I get a message like this:

> Xcode cannot run using the selected device.
>
> No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS
>   version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to
>   run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

When I open the Organizer on either device (one is an iPad 2 the other is an old iPhone 3G) they both display a yellow dot. On the iPad it says my software version is 5.1 yet it won't work. On both devices it says something along the lines of:

> The version of iOS on “iPad” does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK.

Fixes that were offered on other threads that I have tried an saw no results were:

-Click the "Use For Development" (or somehting along those lines) in the Devices section in the Organizer... its not there.

-I have tried redownloading and installing the Provisioning Certificate for the particular app I'm trying to run... It doesn't work nor does it say it is expired.

-I have tried changing the Deployment Target as suggested because of a bug... Still wouldn't work.

-I have tried quitting Xcode and restarting it... Doesn't work.

-I have tried installing updates for my computer along with a restart... Doesn't work.

-I have tried running other Xcode projects... Doesn't work and causes the same problem.

Does anyone have any other suggestions. This is all pretty frustrating and I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Update to XCode 4.3.1, which is the version to use with iOS 5.
2. Make sure your certs haven't expired. They only last a year.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to upgrade to Lion and keep Snow Leopard with Xcode 4.2 you could use the instructions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565/is-is-possible-to-get-the-ios-5-1-sdk-for-use-with-xcode-4-2-on-snow-leopard)

> If you have another Mac running Lion + XCode 4.3.1 you can copy the
>   files from:
>
> "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.1
>   (9B176)"
>
> to the equivalent place on your SL Mac: probably
>   "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport"
>
> and also copy 'version.plist' from the Lion machine in the
>   iPhoneOS.platform
>
> folder to the SL machine.
>
> Re-start XCode on the SL machine and re-connect the devices and it
>   seems happy enough.
>
> [If you don't have access to a machine with Lion+4.3.1 you can get the
>   files out of the 4.3.1 DMG which can be downloaded from Apple here:
>   http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.3.1_for_lion/xcode_4.3.1_for_lion.dmg
>
> then mount the DMG, Show Package Contents on the XCode icon and drill
>   down to
>
> /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
>   to
>
> find the files mentioned above.]
>
> You might find it more convenient to use Apples proprietary 'ditto'
>   method (sudo ditto src dest) in the terminal window to copy the
>   folders.

Comment: Seriously, just upgrade to Lion. Using SL is an unsupported hack and it will likely break progressively more as time proceeds. Better to upgrade on your schedule than to be forced to at an inopportune time.