# 5.0 Base SDK app won't install on iPad with 5.1 OS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an ipad device with 5.1 OS and am trying to run a 5.0 base SDK app on this device.

here's my error:

[image: cannot run on selected device error:]

thanks for any help.

[image: from Organizer]

Comment: You need to change your deployment target.

Comment: Is the device provisioned in the provisioning profile you're using? (You're understandably focused on the "compatible iOS version" portion, but perhaps it's simpler than that?)

Comment: yes the device is provisioned in the provisioning profile. In fact I have run it before on this device using this profile. the profile is still valid also

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: I've added another screenshot above with more info. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe from your screenshot that you are running Xcode 4.2 with the iOS 5.0 SDK, in order to deploy to devices running iOS 5.1 you will need to upgrade to the latest version of Xcode (4.3.2) which has the iOS 5.1 SDK and will allow you to deploy your build to a 5.1 device. This upgrade will require OS X 10.7 Lion. Even though you are targeting a version of iOS supported by your version of Xcode, you can not deploy to devices running a newer version of iOS than your SDK supports.

(Lion upgrade alternative https://stackoverflow.com/a/9621226/716216)

Answer (score 2):

Your device UDID is not added in the developer profile you are currently using.
Go to the developer portal, add the device to your account, add it to your development profile, download the profile again, install it and use the new profile to test the build with.

Comment: I've added another screenshot above

Comment: See MDT's answer then. I believe this is the problem. Update xCode (download it from the Mac App Store) and you should be ready.

Answer (score 1):

i thnk you have selected the device as target, and your ipad is not properly attatched to it. if it attched, xcode will show ipad's name

more over. make sure device is added to provisioning profile u'r using