# New iPhone, can't get testing working on it?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

So I had an iPhone set up for testing and development. The lock button got stuck so I took it into Apple to get it replaced. They replaced the phone without a hesitation which is awesome.

I'm trying to develop on this new phone but when I input the new device in my developer portal and set up the new provisioning profile (which I see on my phone as well), everytime I try to export to iOS Device I get the error that no phones are attached/a compatible one needs to be attached or whatever.

I've never really had problems with this before in the past so I'm wondering if someone knows maybe something I missed or something that needs to be changed on the phone or in xCode?

Please help!

PS: I did check to make sure the Identifiers are the same in the provisioning profile and the xCode app.

Comment: Unplug it and connect it back again.  Xcode should show "Checking UDID symbols" in the HUD.

Comment: Yea I'm not seeing that for some reason- It's still showing "iOS Device" instead of the name I have set for the iPhone as well :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you've pushed the "Use this device for development" button in the Xcode organizer!

Comment: I've manually set up the provision profiles because I need to test with GameCenter and in-app purchases. I think it's fine without clicking that- am I wrong?

Comment: You really need to click it. I've just tried to make sure - if you undo this, the device is no longer available in Xcode. Once I click "Use for development", it becomes available again. Note that you can abort the automatic device provisioning which follows, the device will be available anyway.

Comment: Ahh you're right- weird I remember not doing that for my other phone. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm could this be an iOS/Xcode version problem?  If the new phone you got is running 5.x and you haven't updated your iOS/Xcode since this was released then it won't see a 5.x device. (Also the newest version of iOS/Xcode requires Lion OS).

Comment: I have updated to 5.1.1 on the iphone and am currently on xCode 4.2.1 I believe on Snow Leopard. It worked with my old phone with Snow Leopard and 5.1.1

Comment: Hmm well I was just going from my own experience(I couldn't get a 5.1 device to be seen by my iOS/Xcode).  From this thread too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565/is-is-possible-to-get-the-ios-5-1-sdk-for-use-with-xcode-4-2-on-snow-leopard people were having a similar issue.