# Macbook 1,1 - IOS 5.0.1 - Xcode 4.2 - If I develop in this, will it work on current gen devices?

Tags: ios, xcode

I only have the Macbook, which I CANNOT upgrade to Lion.  I'd like to get started developing IOS applications.  I've got an iPod Touch 5.0.1, so I'm good there.  My main question is this-

When I finish making my applications and I deploy them to Apple, will they work just fine on other devices, like iPhone 4S 5.1.1?

Also, if I pay the $100 to Apple to develop, will they support my Xcode 4.2 for the whole year?

Will I be able to deploy my applications using this scenario without fear of Apple cutting me off?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 4.2 is the last officially supported Xcode version that runs on Snow Leopard, but if you do developing on it, anything that works for older iOS's will run on your iDevices running newer OS's.  [You *might* be able to get newer SDK's to run with Xcode 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565/is-is-possible-to-get-the-ios-5-1-sdk-for-use-with-xcode-4-2-on-snow-leopard) but myself, I wouldn't risk it.

I think the big issue you're going to run into is that if you install a new OS onto your iDevice for testing, you may end up not being able to use your device for testing (in the Xcode organizer).  So you probably want to keep at least one device back on the last supported iOS version for Xcode 4.2.

And this should take care of you for the whole year.

And hopefully you'll make enough money from whatever app you're building to afford a Macintosh where you can run Mountain Lion (OS 10.8) and Xcode 4.4 or 5 or whatever will be out a year from now.

Comment: I do plan on keeping the iPod Touch on 5.0.1, so if what you say is true, I'm golden!  One more question- if I create an .ipa file, and run it on a jailbroken iPhone 4S, 5.1.1, will/should it run?  I'm not that familiar with how Xcode works, and if I can even produce an ipa file to run.

Comment: you can create ipa files, you have to be registered to the apple devs program though.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.
2. Yes.
3. Yes.

It really doesn't matter which Xcode do you have. You can even have Xcode 3 ;)