# xCode 4.2.3 can not compile to iOS 5.1.1 (9B208) or iOS 5.1.1 (9B206)

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, xcode4.2, ios5.1

Yesterday after about a whole nights tinkering i manage to compile for 5.1.1
That was after i downgraded from iOS 5.1.1 (9B208) to iOS 5.1.1 (9B206) as a last desperate attempt.

But today afte a restart im back to square one.
When i go to the organizer and select devices from the top menu i get the following text as before:

> The version of iOS on “xs iPhone” does not match any of the versions
>   of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS
>   SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or
>   update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.
>
> OS Installed on xs iPhone
>   5.1.1 (9B206)
>
> Xcode Supported iOS Versions Latest
>   5.0 (9A334)
>   4.3
>   4.2

I feel completely dumbfounded that it has to be so vastly complicated getting xcode and iOS go together.
But lets say i clean out xcode and reinstall my iphone.
Is there a safe way to compile for the latest IOS "currently 5.1.1"?

Comment: Xcode 4.2.3 is *not* the latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you need to install the latest version of Xcode, which is 4.3.2.

We recently had this problem after the latest iOS update and upgrading Xcode solved it just fine.

Comment: I did that too.
It just took me a little while to find the new location of the app executable.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems until I upgraded my Xcode to the latest version. Upgrading should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I can not upgrade to Xcode 4.3.x because I am still running Snow Leopard and 4.2 still is the latest Xcode version. I solved the issue after following the steps in this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9621226/467813