# Will Xcode 4.3.2 suffice to build apps for iOS 6?

Tags: ios, xcode

After today's announcement that iOS 6 Beta is available to developers today, I am wondering if I jump on the iOS 6 ASAP will I still be able to build my apps in progress on my device(iPhone) from Xcode 4.3.2? or will there be a required update for Xcode as well?

Update: Currently I have iOS 6 on my iPhone and Xcode 4.5 installed. After that the organizer in Xcode (4.3.2 and 4.5) said 'could not support development' in the Provisioning.  Then fixed that, and now I have 4.3.2 saying that it is running my app on my iPhone, but its not showing up on my phone.  And 4.5 gets to the 'TakingInstallLock' point in the process, and just keeps trying, but getting nowhere.  Anyone else having this issue? Anyone know of a solution?

Comment: before you download Xcode 4.5 or iOS 6, make sure to read through the warnings: "Xcode 4.5 Developer Preview cannot be used to submit apps to the iOS or Mac App Store. Continue to use the publicly released version of Xcode to compile and submit apps to the App Stores."

Comment: i've upgraded to ios 6 and now can't test my 5.1 apps on my ios 6 device. trying to find a workaround though.

Comment: Let us all know when you do. It would help all of us out!

Comment: You CAN do it.

See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172231/tutorial-how-to-use-previous-versions-of-xcode-to-build-on-unsupported-versions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can push apps to your phone from Xcode 4.3.x if your phone is running the iOS 6 Beta.

You cannot, however, utilize any of the iOS 6+ frameworks such as the new Social framework from within Xcode 4.3.x

Comment: OP can follow instructions on previous Xcode update, you can push to ios6 on Xcode 4.0, if you clone several directories from Xcode-4.5.dmg to the appropriate Supported Device/Simulator Folder. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565

Comment: Confirming I can build and install apps using organizer to ios6 beta ipod, using Xcode 4.3.3....

Comment: Confirming I can build + sync app on XCode 4.2 to iOS6 device,... but without much debugging facilities (better upgrade to latest OSX ;-)  I skipped cloning 1 directory above.

Comment: How did you put the app on iOS6? In my organizer, it says:
The version of iOS on “xxxx” does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment yet so this is to confirm that installing Xcode 4.5 DP acutally installs the iOS 6 SDK for Xcode 4.3.2 as well. This is rather obvious as SDK files are installed in a general place (namely the Library folder) of OSX.

The steps to use your updated iOS 6 device for development with Xcode 4.3.2 thus are:

Download Xcode 4.5 DP from the dev area of apple.com.

Install Xcode 4.5

Start up Xcode 4.3.2

Open up the devices section, choose your device for development, wait for the process of fetching information to finish and you are good to go.

Regards!

Comment: So, you did all this steps? Can you now build your apps in progress to your updated ios 6 device from Xcode 4.3.2???

Comment: Yes. I have iOS Beta 6 on my iPhone 4 and can deploy Apps from Xcode 4.3.2 using the iOS 6 SDK Beta that came with the Xcode 4.5 install. There are no pitfalls during the installation so you can just go ahead and try for yourself!

Answer (score 2):

Any apps that you write using beta software will be rejected. To translate, if you use iOS 6 SDK beta or the new Xcode beta that gets released today, your app will be rejected even if you make a build for just iOS 5.

Comment: I was just talking about updating my device.

Answer (score 1):

I installed iOS6 and Xcode 4.3.2 didn't recognize my device. After installing Xcode 4.5 beta and letting it install a few things, 4.3.2 now recognizes my device and I can carry on building and testing on my iOS6 device.

Comment: Can anyone else confirm they experienced the same thing? I will try later on when I get home from work.

Comment: Actually, i've just done another mac that's got Xcode 4.3.3. I can build and run fine without having installed 4.5. You have to wait about 10 minutes while it downloads stuff from phone, just watch Organizer and you should see it downloading.

Comment: I did this and my iMac from 2011 running OS X 10.7.4 thinks I want to run on 'My Mac 64-bit' when using 4.3.2, but works just fine with 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

I would say no! 
I updated last night and now I can't run my app on my phone.

Comment: Same here. I'm assuming we need to update to the Xcode beta too? But will we then have to uninstall that and reinstall 4.3.2 before building an app to submit?

Comment: I've just read the release notes for Xcode 4.5 and it seems it installs as a separate bundle. So I guess we need to have both installed for now. Use 4.5 to test your app, then 4.3.2 to submit it.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Installed the 4.5 but still can't build on the phone from neither 4.3.3 or 4.5