# Use previous versions of Xcode to build on unsupported versions of iOS

Tags: xcode, ios6

I have been frustrated that I have had to use the very buggy XCode 4.5 to build to my device after having upgraded to iOS 6 .

Unfortunately, this version of Xcode for some reason does not allow my app to push or pop view controllers... an issue that completely goes away when I switch back to XCode 4.3.2.

I wanted to be able to use XCode 4.3.2 to build to my iOS 6 device, but this is officially not supported in 4.3.2 because it does not support anything greater than 5.x.

Is there a workaround or fix for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a fix for the issue:

1) When you install the latest developer release of XCode, leave the previous version on your computer

2) Make sure the previous version of XCode is quit and then open the developer release version and open the Organizer window

3) Open the old version of XCode and open the Organizer window

4) Click back on the old version of XCode and your device should now show under the run scheme drop-down menu. You should now be able to build and run on your "unsupported" device.

NOTE: This worked for me with XCode 4.3.2 and XCode 4.5 building on iOS 6 for the iPhone 4S. It may or may not work on future versions of XCode or iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I hardly ever get out of Xcode.  I was receiving this error "unsupported device (null)" and I tried clean, switching USB ports, switching devices to no avail.

I exited and reentered Xcode without even unplugging my device and it fixed the problem.  When the "unsupported device" is given, I noticed that no icon (like a little iPhone) next to my device name was displayed.  After I restarted Xcode, I saw the icon and knew my problem was resolved.