# Can not test App on device with iOS 5.1.1?

Tags: ios, testing, device

I recently upgrade iPad to iOS 5.1.1. Organizer prompted "the Xcode can not find the software and image to the install this version."
"Could not support development."

[image: Organizer screen]

The Xcode 4.2 supports up to SDK 5.0.
The Xcode 4.3.3 supports up to the SDK 5.1, but does not support SDK 5.1.1, Is that right?

So there is no way to test on 5.1.1 device, isn't it?

p.s.
I am working on Mac OS X 10.6.8 and Xcode 4.2. According to [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565/is-is-possible-to-get-the-ios-5-1-sdk-for-use-with-xcode-4-2-on-snow-leopard) I has copied "5.1 (9B176)" to the corresponding folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For testing on iOS 5.1 you need Mac OS 10.7 Lion and Xcode 4.3. iOS 5.1 support is only available with Xcode 4.3 so you cannot test on a 5.1 device using earlier versions.

Comment: The upgrade takes time and my iMac configurations in general so I was a little hesitant. I downloaded the Xcode 4.3.3 (of course, can not install), I found the SDK 5.1 in the package, but there is no SDK 5.1.1. So I want to make sure Lion + Xcode 4.3.3 will support to test on iOS 5.1.1 (not 5.1) device? If it can, I'll upgrade the Mac OS X and the Xcode. Thanks your help.

Comment: Yes i too faced the problem when i update my iphone with ios 5.1.1
I have upgraded to lion os 10.7.3 and installed xcode 4.3.2 after that go to software update in apple home button So your system will be updated and you can execute ios5.1.1 in xcode 4.3

Answer (score 0):

SugarMEmE, just a thought, since u need to copy it manually, u need standalone iOS5.1.1sdk. I checked Xcodes4.2.x up to Xcode4.5, they do not have iOS5.1.1, just 5.1 and then 6.0. No intermediates. So if somebody has a Lion w Xcode4.2 or higher, that can download those intermediates automatically, you technically just could copy it from there.

Hei, just did it. You need to find a file iPad1,1_5.1.1_9B206_restore.ipsw say here: http://mytopfiles.com/other/file/iPad1,1_5-1-1_9B206_Restore/589434.htm

It was on my other Mac (that has Lion and Xcode 4.3) in Library\iTunes\iPad Software Updates\
I just copied it on my Mac (Snow Leopard w Xcode4.2) in the same Library\iTunes\iPad Software Updates.
Image immediately showed up in Xcode Organizer Library Software Images.
And right away I was able to build on my iPad1 with iOS5.1.1

Logically, if you need it for iPad2 you would look for iPad2,1_5.1.1_9B206_restore.ipsw http://mytopfiles.com/other/file/iPad2,1_5-1-1_9B206_Restore/589852.htm etc, I guess.

Regards,
B

PS after all, u do not need to pay for upgrade to Lion yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can generally link to the DeviceSupport folder for a similar OS version.

I just did this for 5.1.1 and it worked:

```
sudo ln -s 5.1 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.1.1
```

Comment: This is Xcode 4.5 on Mountain Lion, BTW. Which doesn't have a 5.1.1 SDK apparently either.