# Failure to install AIR 3.3 application into iOS simulator

Tags: ios, air, ios-simulator

When I try to install the app into the simulator (adt -installApp) I get:-

> Unknown or unsupported SDK version: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk

I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.4 (Lion) and I'm trying to use the iPhone simulator as per [support for iOS simulator blog post](https://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/05/06/using-new-simulator-support-feature-for-ios/). I've tried different versions of the sdk (5.1,5.0,4.3,4.0) and I get the same result.

I'm using Flash Builder 4.6 and I've updated the sdk to Air 3.3 as per [this article](http://www.flashdeveloper.co/post/10985842021/overlay-adobe-air-32-in-flash-builder-46) and I've extracted the sdk from XCode 4.4 per [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565/is-is-possible-to-get-the-ios-5-1-sdk-for-use-with-xcode-4-2-on-snow-leopard).

What am I doing wrong and what do I need to do to get it working?