# Compiling Titanium (Appcelerator) app in xcode produces warnings and errors

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, titanium, appcelerator

I am currently using OSX Snow Leopard with Xcode 4.2 and Titanium v 2.1.1. and I installed iOS 5.1.1 Sdk as per this quesiton: [How to get iOS 5.1 SDK on Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565/is-is-possible-to-get-the-ios-5-1-sdk-for-use-with-xcode-4-2-on-snow-leopard).

However when I try to build my generated xcode project file from the Titanium studio in Xcode I get a whole bunch of warnings. See image. I have set the base sdk target as 5.0 for the app in Xcode. Can't find much on Google or their forums.

[image: Errors in Xcode on build from titanium project]

I tried creating a new project and copying the contents of resources over and still get these warnings. Is there a better way and of course a fix? I need to get this app complete for this weekend and this is making me nervous that the app store will reject it.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's the way a Titanium project looks like. If you're app is compiling and you're not receiving **errors**, you should consider yourself happy.

App Store will not reject your app because it has warnings. They won't even see that. You're getting compilation warnings and they are not visible on the binary you send to Apple.

Comment: Great thanks for this! I had a feeling this was the case. I am just going to use the compiler in Titanium studio