# Will installing XCode 4.5 remove iOS Simulator 5.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode4.5

I have 2 machines. On one of them I updated to xcode 4.5, but doing so uninstalled my iOS simulator for 5.1.

I'm hesitant to update my other machine as I have a project that requires the 5.1 simulator.

Are my assumptions correct or did I do something to remove the older simulator without knowing?

Comment: http://www.walterpalladino.com/manual-installation-of-simulators-on-xcode/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can redownload the simulator in the Xcode preferences.

[image]

Comment: Why would it uninstall the previous versions? It makes no sense at all!

Comment: I just updated to Xcode 4.5 (4G182). I can't figure out why the iOS 6.0 Simulator isn't showing up! I only see 5.1, 5.0 and the Command Line Tools, as shown above in the image.

Comment: The iOS6 simulator is already installed by default so it doesn't come up for download.

Comment: Does installing the iOS 5.1 simulator also install the 5.1 SDK?

Comment: I just installed the iOS 5.1 simulator, and: nope. You have to get the iOS 5.1 SDK from - well, I have no idea, actually. Apparently not Apple, any more. Searching for "iOS 5.1 SDK" gives you the iOS 6 download. Evidently if you still support "old" versions of iOS, you weren't supposed to update to Xcode 4.5. Wish it told me that **before** I updated, I kind of figured that a single version back would still be supported. I mean, simulators for 5.0 and 4.3 are still available, but the only iOS SDK I have is 6.0.

Comment: I installed many simulators. And some of them appears to be useless to me. Installing the simulators is ok, but is there a way to uninstall some of them to spare room ?

Comment: You should always build with the latest SDK. You can still support iOS5 with the iOS6 SDK.

Comment: It may be possible to download an old XCode and then link the SDKs : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565/is-it-possible-to-get-the-ios-5-1-sdk-for-xcode-4-2-on-snow-leopard

Comment: As Ben said above -- you don't need to install the 5.1 SDK. If you set your base SDK to the latest, you can set your deployment target to any earlier version. **99% of the time base SDK should be set to Latest.** `BASESDK = latest. IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = earliest version you want to support installs on`.

Answer (score 6):

Download Xcode 4.3.3 for lion and open the dmg, and click and show package contents,and copy the `Contents\Developer\platforms\iPhoneOS.platform\sdks\iPhoneOs5.1sdk` folders into your xcode4.5 `Contents\Developer\platorms\iPhoneOS.platform\sdks` folder, and it works