# How to install iOS simulator to Xcode 4.5 manually?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a fresh installation of Xcode 4.5.  It doesn't come with iOS 5.0 simulator.  I have downloaded a copy of `ios_50_simulator.dmg` file.

I mounted the .dmg file in OSX, and perform installation directly.  However, the iOS 5.0 simulator doesn't install in my Xcode 4.5 apps.

Any ideas?

Comment: Its answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503575/will-installing-xcode-4-5-remove-ios-simulator-5-1

Answer (score 2):

Open "Preferences" window in Xcode, navigate to Downloads - Components. You can install iOS 5.0 Simulator there.

Comment: I already have .dmg file.  I don't want to download the file again.  Can I perform offline installation?

Comment: I don't think that this installation method is valid anymore.

Comment: @borrrden: I think there must be some where to deploy offline.  As I have few workstations to install the simulator and my internet bandwidth is slow.  Perform offline installing is viable solution for my situation.

Comment: Find where it got installed (I assume it is using Xcode 4.2 locations), you need to look inside the Xcode application -> Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs and there should be various SDK folders there.  I don't know what the inside of the DMG file looks like because it is not available for download anymore (hence, not valid) but try to find a folder that looks like that and copy it.