# Import iOS 6 SDK into Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-snow-leopard, ios6

I installed Xcode 4.2 on a Snow Lopard and when iOS SDK was published I imported the iOS 5.1 SDK following this topic [Is it possible to get the iOS 5.1 SDK for Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565/is-is-possible-to-get-the-ios-5-1-sdk-for-use-with-xcode-4-2-on-snow-leopard)

Now I need to import iOS 6 SDK and I would know if this tutorial is still working for iOS 6 SDK.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried following the tutorial that you have linked.
It works perfectly for me. Just copy "6.0" instead of "5.1".

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me (after "su -", so I'm running as root), and with the Xcode 4.5 .dmg file mounted as a disk drive.

```
echo copying iPhoneOS6.0.sdk
cp -R /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk               /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/

echo copying iphonesim6.0.sdk
cp -R /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/

echo copying devicesupport for 6.0
cp -R /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/6.0\ \(10A403\)                 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/

#remove old -latest- link
rm -f /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/Latest

echo setting up Latest link
cd /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/
ln -s ./6.0\ \(10A403\) ./Latest
```

Note: Xcode dmg file available from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode  (1.56 GB)

Comment: Does iPhoneSimulator 6.0 run on snow leopard?

Comment: yeah, I'd like to know that one too - doeas simulator work on snow leopard?

Answer (score 3):

With a Intel Core Duo (32 bit) running Snow Leopard the iOS 6 simulator doesn't work (because some of the libraries are missing 32 bit variants).

It also appears that while it is possible to test on an iPhone 4 device upgraded to iOS6 by copying the iPhoneOS.platform files but it does not appear to be possible to do the same with an iPhone 5. I assume this is due to the new armv7s format on the device.

So what you can do depends on your mac and your iOS device.

Comment: This seems to work initially, but I get the following error when I attempt to switch between viewControllers when I am debug testing with my device: Error Starting Executable “AppName" Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 453. @Tony Do you know why?  Do you want to copy all files from iPhoneOS.platform to the proper XCode directory or just the ones mentioned in the link in the beginning?

Answer (score 2):

For the building of Cordova projects the same procedure works, however you will probably get this error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
>   Referenced from:
>   /Developer42/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /Developer42/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib:
>   unknown required load command 0x80000023 Command
>   /Developer42/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255

This build fail happens because of `/Classes/MainViewController.xib` which is not compatible with iOS 6.... *i think ;)*

The workaround:

Select your projects target and expand the Supporting Files folder. Inside this folder, click on any file **OTHER THAN**  `MainViewController.xib`.  You need to expose the File Inspector. After you expose the File Inspector, select the file `MainViewController.xib`. At this point xcode will try to crash, don't let it!... just keep pressing *Continue* in the crash prompt until the File Inspectors settings changes to reflect the .xib file. You should keep pressing *Continue* until you get past the crash prompts such that you can make edits to the File Inspector. In the File Inpsector, under **Target Membership** unselect the target.

[image]

Close xcode, reopen and all should be golden!!

Avoid selecting `MainViewController.xib` in the future as it will crash your session.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my views are in the App and the App reports it cannot find the MainWindow.  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/643CA904-59EA-4AD2-9603-FAA2F4EC9EFA/angryheartsfree.app> (loaded)' with name 'MainWindow''

Comment: Does iPhoneSimulator 6.0 run on snow leopard?

Comment: @rraallvv: No it does not.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to import the iOS 6 SDK into Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard, but when I tried to build one of my old projects, I got the same errors that iOSGuru mentioned. The troublemaker seems to be the iOS 6 simulator. Once I removed the iOS 6 simulator, my old project built normally using "Latest iOS(iOS 6.0)" selected as the Base SDK. That means I can't test on the iOS 6 simulator, but I'm testing on my real device running iOS 6 so I don't think that's such a big deal.

I haven't tried to build anything using iOS 6 features yet, so there's a chance something might still break there, but omitting the iOS 6 simulator seems to let me build with the iOS 6 SDK.