# iOS simulator cannot find sdk iOS 6 on snow leopard

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, ios6

I read this post:

[Import iOS 6 SDK into Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508357/import-ios-6-sdk-into-xcode-4-2-on-snow-leopard)

and i have the follow problem:

I launched the script and it seems finished correctly, but when i open iPhone simulator and i select version 6 in the hardware option i see this message: iOS simulator cannot find developer kit. Then i select sdk 6 but doesn't work.

What can i do?

Thank you!