# ios development on snow leopard

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-snow-leopard

Unsure if this issue is related to snow leopard, but this build does work on a machine running Lion, but that might not be the only difference.

I have xcode 4.2 with the ios 6.1 simulator.

I am getting a pretty generic error that is blocking my development "cannot compile data model for path [path to momd file]"

Here is the full error log:

> DataModelVersionCompile
>   /.../Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-abcdefg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp.momd
>   /.../MyApp.xcdatamodeld
>       setenv PATH /Developer/usr/bin/momc -XD_MOMC_SDKROOT=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk
>   -XD_MOMC_IOS_TARGET_VERSION=6.1 -MOMC_PLATFORMS iphonesimulator -MOMC_PLATFORMS iphoneos -XD_MOMC_TARGET_VERSION=10.6 /.../Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp.momd
>
> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
>   Referenced from:
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib:
>   unknown required load command 0x80000023 2013-06-01 17:14:40.374
>   momc[72001:607] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data
>   is empty; did you forget to send -finishEncoding to the
>   NSKeyedArchiver? /.../MyApp.xcdatamodeld:0: error: Compilation failed
>   for data model at path
>   '/.../Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp.momd/MyApp.mom'

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure about "xcode 4.2 with the ios 6.1 simulator"? iOS 6.1 support was introduced with Xcode 4.6.

Comment: Sounds like your core data files may be corrupted

Comment: yes i'm sure.  used this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508357/import-ios-6-sdk-into-xcode-4-2-on-snow-leopard

Comment: Also, same error when using 5.0 simulator by the way