# iOS6 development on Snow Leopard

Tags: xcode, xcode4, osx-snow-leopard, osx-mountain-lion, downgrade

I'm on Mountain Lion at the moment but the battery life is terrible and I'm thinking of downgrading back to Snow Leopard. The only thing is, now that we have to submit our apps for the 4-inch screen of the iPhone 5, will the last Xcode build supported on SL (4.2 I believe?) be able to build these apps? Or am I completely stuck on ML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest Xcode with which you can use the 4-inch iPhone simulator runs only on Mountain Lion.

**However,** if you don't mind not using Xcode, you can extract the essential parts of the toolchain (the compiler and the headers + libraries) and use the `clang` compiler from the command line - it should run just fine even on SnowLeopard and compile your apps.

Answer (score 1):

You are stucked to Mountain Lion! :)
Xcode 4.2 doesn't have support for ios6, neither iphone 5 nor ipad mini

Comment: you can support iOS 6 if you import proper folders from newer Xcode - like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565/is-it-possible-to-get-the-ios-5-1-sdk-for-xcode-4-2-on-snow-leopard - but that seems to be impossible for simulator :/