# XCode v4.2 and Default-568h@2x.png --> "Invalid Binary" Message When Submitting iOS App

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4.2

I spent many hours trying to figure this issue out.  Apple continuously accepted my uploaded binary when I was submitting my app through XCode4.2, yet only to declare the binary invalid minutes later.  It turned out that it was because I had placed the "Default-568h@2x.png" in my resources folder in an attempt to support iPhone 5's splash screen and eliminate "letterbox mode" (black top and bottom bars)...  I am using a 2006 MacBook Pro, and thus am unable to upgrade to Lion OS or Xcode4.5.  Also, I am able to build AdHoc versions for my customer that runs just fine on the iPhone 5 (filling its entire screen).

Does anyone know of a workaround I can implement to get Apple to accept my binary while still being able to support iPhone 5's larger screen (no black top or bottom bars)?  If I re-name "Default-568h@2x.png" I am able to get Apple to accept my binary, but will I lose compatibility with iPhone5?

I found the following link in my search, which seems to suggest the startup image has nothing to do with the iPhone 5's letterbox mode, and can be labeled any name.  However, I must admit, I am rather lost when the writer begins discussing 'viewports' and 'media queries'...

http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/iphone-5-ios-6-html5-developers

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: There should be some explanation why apple is considering your binary as 'invalid'. Maybe your iPhone 5 launch image png image was 'interlaced'? PNG images for Icon and launches has to be 'non-interlaced'.

Comment: check that image size is 640x1136 or if you renamed that "Default-568h@2x.jpg" to "Default-568h@2x.png", it might also be the problem.

Comment: I think you will not lose compatibility with `iPhone5`. Have you checked it in `iPhone 5` how splash screen see without `Default-568h@2x.png` ?

Comment: Are you trying to update your application after certain period ? I mean long time more than 4/5 months ? I am sure there is nothing wrong with the image there is other issue.

Comment: Including "Default-568h@2x.png" in the AppStore build that I created with XCode4.2 is definitely the issue.  If I remove the file or rename it, then iTunes Connect will not display the "Invalid Binary" message, but instead will display "Waiting for Review".  Apple did not send a follow-up e-mail explaining why.
I found the following link describing the same problem: 
<http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/153862-Good-to-know-iOS-4-5-6-and-invalid-binary>
However, I am trying to see if there may be a workaround, so that I do not need to go out and replace my 2006 MacBook Pro... @Jennis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to install iOS 6.0 SDK on my XCode v4.2 following these instructions:
[Is it possible to get the iOS 5.1 SDK for Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565/is-it-possible-to-get-the-ios-5-1-sdk-for-xcode-4-2-on-snow-leopard)
Afterwards, I could create a binary with the below attributes that Apple would accept.

- The launch image Default-568h@2x.png
- The setting of Base SDK being iOS 6 (or later)

Answer (score 11):

Apple has made a deliberate decision to only allow two types of apps:

1. Apps built with XCode 4.4 and earlier, built for iOS up to version 5, including support for *armv6* (required for iPhone 3G) but without support for iOS 6 and without support for the larger screen of the iPhone 5.
2. Apps built with XCode 4.5, built for at least iOS 4.3, possibly supporting the larger screens (`Default-568h@2x.png`) but without support for iOS before 4.3 and without support for the *armv6* architecture (required for iPhone 3G).

All others apps are now rejected if you upload them to the App Store. Your app is rejected because it's includes `Default-568h@2x.png` and one the following things: either *armv6* support or support for iOS before 4.3.

Without XCode 4.5, it's impossible to create an app the support the larger iPhone 5 screen and is accepted by Apple.

Some people have managed to build and upload applications the support both iPhone 3G and iPhone 5. But this is very tricky and requires a parallel installation of at least XCode 4.5 and one earlier version.

**Update:**

If I'm not mistaken, the crucial points for supporting the larger screen are:

- The launch image `Default-568h@2x.png`
- The setting of *Base SDK* being *iOS 6* (or later)

If you add the launch image without setting the *Base SDK* to *iOS 6*, iTunes Connect will reject you app:

> "Invalid Launch Image - You app contains a launch image with a size modifier that is only supported for apps built with the iOS 6.0 SDK or later."

Without XCode 4.5, you cannot select *iOS 6* as the *Base SDK*.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, @Codo.  Can you point me to some official documentation that explains Apple's position on this app separation that you have described above (apps built with XCode4.4 or earlier, and those with XCode4.5 or greater)?

Comment: No, I can't give you any official documentation for that. They might exist. I just wouldn't know where to find them. For a short time, it was possible to upload apps with the 4 inch launch screen built for an old iOS version. But on September 27 or 28, Apple began to reject these apps with the above error message. And fact is (and probably documented somewhere) that XCode 4.5 no longer supports the armv6 architecture and thus can no longer build apps for the iPhone 3G.

Answer (score 1):

I have have a Mac mini from 2006, running Snow Leopard, Xcode 4.2. I was having the exact same problem with my submissions last night (May 2, 2013). Organizer uploads the app, and says all is fine. Within a couple of minutes The email below comes through. I did what the email suggested. Then I double checked, triple checked all settings, recreated certificates/profiles....still invalid binary.

Early in development, I was able to crack a dmg to get iOS6 installed on my machine. I put `Default-568h@2x.png` in my app. I tested ad hoc installations on a 5th gen iPod Touch - everything worked fine, BUT Apple won't accept my app.

I was going to get a new mac this year anyway. I'm heading to the Apple store to get one tonight. Here's the email from Apple:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "Gazoodle Colours". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> Invalid Signature - Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page and click "Ready to Upload Binary." Continue through the submission process until the app status is "Waiting for Upload." You can then deliver the corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

Update: Got a new macbook pro, built my app with the latest Xcode (4.6.2) and resubmitted the app. My app is finally in the Waiting for Review state. Wasn't sure buying a new computer would solve the problem, but it was a good excuse to upgrade the hardware, and it actually fixed the invalid binary issue!