# XCode 4.2 with iOS 6 SDK: Unable to Debug with iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4.2

I recently upgraded my XCode 4.2 to utilize the iOS 6 SDK (Mac is too old to install Lion and XCode 4.5) following these instructions here:
[Is it possible to get the iOS 5.1 SDK for Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565/is-it-possible-to-get-the-ios-5-1-sdk-for-xcode-4-2-on-snow-leopard)

Everything seems to work fine (i.e. creating builds to upload to the app store with iOS 6 as the base SDK, generating builds for the customer to test, able to detect devices with iOS 6 installed).

Unfortunately, though, I get the following error when I try and run on my iPhone 4 (iOS 6) in debug mode, after attempting to switch between my simple viewControllers:

- Error Starting Executable “AppName" - Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 453.

The process number above seems to be constantly different whenever I give it a shot.  Also, the app works fine on the iOS 5 simulator or if I stop debug mode and open up the version that gets installed on my device.

Anyone have any insight into how I can solve this issue for running debug mode on my device?

Thanks in Advance!