# running iOS Simulator on Snow Leopard

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm currently running Snow Leopard and I have Xcode 3.2.6 installed. I'd like to be able to run an iOS Simulator, preferably the 5.x series but I'd settle for anything really. How do I do that? I found this question: [Is it possible to get the iOS 5.1 SDK for Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565/is-it-possible-to-get-the-ios-5-1-sdk-for-xcode-4-2-on-snow-leopard) but that requires Xcode 4.2, which I can't seem to find for Snow Leopard.

I don't really even plan to do any app development on Xcode - this is mostly for testing browser stuff - so if there's a way to run the simulator without Xcode that would be good too. I have a physical iPad as well in case that helps.

Comment: Where did you download xCode? this link has the whole bundle including the simulator (not 5): https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode%203.2.6

Comment: I am running Xcode 4.2 on Leopard, but this worked only with some manual work.

Comment: @RobotWoods trying that now. Will report back.

Comment: @RobotWoods that did in fact work. Make it an answer and I'll accept. I still don't understand why I can't get Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard since it was clearly available at one time, but that's a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link for the entire bundle for Snow Leopard including the simulator (not 5): http://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode%203.2.6

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your OS to install latest simulators. It will not work in snow leopard.

Answer (score 0):

Update to OS/X Mountain Lion, then you'll be able to install XCode 4.X and run iOS 5 and 6 simulators