# Jailcoder 1.2.1 / XCode 4.2 for Snowleopard / iOS 5.1.1 - Build Fails adding Project to iPhone 4S

Tags: xcode4.2, ios5.1, iphone-4

looking for a bit of help.
I'm new to Mac as well as XCode, I borrowed a Mac from my friend because I needed to develop an iPhone app.  The app is working fine in the simulator so I want to try it on my phone.  Since I'm not a paid developer and my phone is jailbroken I found the program Jailcoder.

I followed these instructions to get the iOS 5.1 SDK working on XCode 4.2:  [Is it possible to get the iOS 5.1 SDK for Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565/is-it-possible-to-get-the-ios-5-1-sdk-for-xcode-4-2-on-snow-leopard)

I then installed Jailcoder 1.2.1 and ran through the setup.
I patched XCode as well as my project.

When I try to build to my iphone it fails with this error:

/Users/Ryan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Wireless_Controller-amuortpwndtvqfdoyyamsuhsssbu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Wireless Controller.app/: CSSMERR_TP_CERT_NOT_VALID_YET
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

I see the words "cert" and "not valid yet" so I thought it might have something to do with the certificates Jailcoder installed.

Any ideas on this? I need to get this project on my phone soon... Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a pro. I'm also beginner.
But, let me share what i know.

1. Uninstall your xcode and Reinstall Xcode. After install, don't open it.(To get un-touch new Xcode)
2. Open JailCoder, patch your Xcode and project.  (Now, You can touch your Xcode)
3. Connect your jailbroken device with your Mac.
4. In Xcode open your project, choose your device and click Product > Build.
5. After Build, click Run.

That is all i know.

In my  Mac OSX 10.8, Xcode 4.5, iPAD 2, iOS 5.1.1 is OK.
It install my app on iPAD.
;)

Thanks.