# AdSupport Framework not found

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.3

I have been able to make xCode 4.3.2 work with iOS 6.0 using the technique described here [Is it possible to get the iOS 5.1 SDK for Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565/is-it-possible-to-get-the-ios-5-1-sdk-for-xcode-4-2-on-snow-leopard)

When I add AdSupport.framework or other iOS 6 specific frameworks, it builds fine against the iOS device scheme with no device connected. However, as soon as I connect an iOS device it gives erros 'framework not found AdSupport'. It does not even compile against iOS Simulator 5.1

I am using iOS 6.0 as base sdk and tried deployment target of 4.3 upto 5.1 but still same error.

Answer (score 1):

AdSupport.framework is only available beginning on iOS6.

You should mark the framework as Optional (Weak Reference) and ensure that when running on iOS  versions below 6, that the AdSupport code is not called.