# Xcode 4.2 + iOS6 = Interface Builder error

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, interface-builder, xcode4.2

I am trying to use the new iOS6 SDK with an old version of Xcode, 4.2. And I really need to be this way.
I have followed this instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9621226/987480

Everything seems to be OK, but when I have tried to compile, I got an error about Interface Builder

[image]

In Base SDK I have Latest iOS(iOS 6.1). Is anyone having the same problem? Any workaround, or a different way of getting an old Xcode+iOS6 SDK working?

Thanks a lot.

EDITED: Besides I can not edit any xib files, everytime I got a Crash Error

Comment: Restart the simulator and check.

Comment: It says there's a crash report at Console.app, might worth to have a look.

Comment: I did not even start the simulator. It happens when trying to BUILD

Comment: @A-Live the Console give me the same information you can see in the picture above and a lot of more not understandable errors

Answer (score 0):

install xcode again, it works for me