# Trying to deploy to iPhone 5 with iOS 6 SDK, on XCode 4.2

Tags: xcode, ios6, osx-snow-leopard, ios6.1, hackintosh

I'm running XCode 4.2 on Snow Leopard 10.6.8 on a Dell Mini 1010. So it's a hackintosh. Anyway I already managed to get ios 5.1 SDK installed and I can debug applications on my iPad 1st gen running 5.1 which is great. (Following this method [Is it possible to get the iOS 5.1 SDK for Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565/is-it-possible-to-get-the-ios-5-1-sdk-for-xcode-4-2-on-snow-leopard))

Now I also installed ios 6 SDK along with the device support files for 6.0. However my iPhone is running 6.1.4 which means I require the 10B350 device support file. Does anyone know where I can get this? My iPhone shows up in the organizer panel with this message "dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failed"

Now I can also develop apps with the iphone 6 sdk, which works fine. And I even have the developer certificate installed on my iPhone 5.

So it seems to be an intitialisation error within xcode?

Help or tips appreciated.

Cheers

Ben