# iPad black blank Screen Issue

Tags: ios, ipad

I have recently updated my iPad device to version 6.1.3, it was OK till i have not installed Xcode 5.0, now when i run one of my application in this device, many of the times i get Black Blank Screen, in the half of ipad Screen, like the image is showing. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried the following tricks:
 1. language change.
 2. shutting device off and then On again.
 3. switched WiFi network...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you select your device to run, there's two listed devices, select the first one, that uses SDK 6.
If your list contains only one, you'll have to download SDK 6 and copy to Xcode folder: just like this link [Is it possible to get the iOS 5.1 SDK for Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565/is-it-possible-to-get-the-ios-5-1-sdk-for-xcode-4-2-on-snow-leopard) but using SDK 6.

Comment: I think its not the solution for my issue, m able to run the app using Xcode 5.0 on all other devices(from IOS 4.3.2 to IOS 7 device) without this issue, i have problem only with this device. i have updated iPad3 to version 7.0.2, and its working fine in it.