# How to build a release version of iPad app on xCode

Tags: build, xcode4

I actually need to get the .app file of a xcode application. I have tried searching for an answer and I found a similar question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984727/how-to-get-app-file-of-a-xcode-application). I have tried:

[image]

after building the application, when I go to my app folder I cannot find the build folder that everyone talks about. I already have the Ad Hoc Distribution Provisioning Profile in order to send the app. I just need to send an app to a friend and I have already created the Ad Hoc Distribution Provisioning Profile. I believe I am just missing the .app file.

Comment: Have you changed build configuration in edit schema to the "Ad Hoc"? Can you find build folder? At least according the settings on the picture you posted you are missing Ad Hoc Code Signing Identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a doc from apple how to do that correctly, 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html