# iPhone: developing with IOS 4.3 on IOS5 device not possible?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have ios5 installed on my iPhone device, I am developing an application in xcode using SDK IOS 4.3 I got the error:

*The version of iOS on "John's iPhone” does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.*

I dont want to do either of them, because I have other ongoing projects since months which I started with using IOS 4.3. So if I download IOS 5 SDK is that possible that I will mess things up with previous projects? And do I have to download all xcode 4.2 again for IOS 5?! and after all.."what the heck is going around?"

Comment: I got Snow Leopard + Xcode 4.2 + iPad with IOS 5.1.1 + iPhone configuration utility (to upload apps to the ipad) to work like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11460561/1208218 - maybe some suggestions there will help you also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear about what your options are...

I suggest you upgrade to Xcode 4.2 and the iOS 5 SDK. That still allows you to write apps for iOS 4.x, but you get a better version of Xcode and a better compiler (LLVM 3.0) and the ability to develop on your iOS 5 device.

Comment: tnx, How can I run my IOS 4 app on the IOS 5 device? assuming i use latest xcode 4.2 with ios 5 sdk installed

Comment: Devices with iOS 5 will run apps targeted to 3.x or 4.x.  Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027120/how-to-make-iphone-app-compatible-with-multiple-sdk-firmware-versions/3027213#3027213) might help you understand more about it.