# How to get the path of an app in iPhone in order to do testing from appium?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, appium

How do find the path name for any app located in my iPhone so I can launch it via Appium? When I open up Appium (1.4.8), I click on the apple icon and am prompted to enter the App path (under iOS settings). If I'm trying to launch an app that's internally located in my iPhone, what do I put for the app path?

Ex: If I want to launch the Weather app from my iPhone on appium via the appium inspector, where can I get the .app path?

I have Xcode 7.0.1 and it is able to recognize my phone as a hardware device available for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Appium framework requires that you have the application file itself available for Appium to install the App. So in this variable you must provide the absolute location of the `.app` or `.ipa` file.

Comment: Where can I get that from?

Answer (score 0):

You can locate your app following the below steps or copy the app file and put it in one of your Desktop folder for easy access.

> Step 1: open finder and press command⌘ + shift⇧ + g
>
> Step 2: paste "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData"
>
> Step 3: select your_app_name-jkfksdfhskdhfksdh some thing like this
>   folder
>
> Step 4:
>   your_app_name-jkfksdfhskdhfksdh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>
> Step 5: You will see 2 files one is your_app_name.app(icon like
>   rounder and 1 cross line ) and 2nd file is your_app_name.app.dSYM

Credits to [veeresh kumbar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7353795/veeresh-kumbar)'s answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984727/how-to-get-app-file-of-a-xcode-application).