# Xcode wait for executable to be launched does not deploy build to simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Using Xcode 6, I want to debug using "wait for executable to be launched". When I press Run, the simulator launches but my app is not visible on the home screen. Normally when "automatic" is highlighted, the build is deployed to the simulator successfully (and automatically launches).

I've tried restarting Xcode, resetting the simulator, and using a different simulator with no luck. All I see is the "Waiting for (app name) to launch..." status with a running spinner in Xcode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you considered doing this from Command Line?

Install:

`xcrun simctl install booted <path to app>`

and run:

`xcrun simctl launch booted <app id>`

---

**<path to app>**

[image]

**<app id>**

[image]

Comment: Found this to locate app path: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1984746/1229612 - reveal it in finder (switch directory Release-iphoneos to Release-iphonesimulator) and then drag the .app file into the terminal to finish the install command above. You can then run the app from the home screen if you wish not to use the launch command